# Is talking to my self out loud and saying bad words haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I don’t know why but I often to to my self is it halal to do that and I say bad words while I talk to my self is it haram

Answer (score 0):

Anything which you do and have bad effects your physical or mental health is haram in Islam. Bad words create bad feelings and intentions which leads to bad actions. If you are saying bad words about you it will cause depression and disappointment. If you are saying bad words about others then it will cause fights. And bad words are coming from bad thoughts

Hazrat Ali RA says "As water drops make a river thoughts make character and faith"

Answer (score 0):

Talking to yourself loud or without voice is not Haram 
Saying bad words – loud or not loud - is Haram, If you did that Estaghfer Allah And Toub Elih immediately and try to not back again